Error thrown when importing values form cantera's "nasa_gas.yaml" for enthalpy calculations
I am developing a Python program that takes two propellants (an oxidizer and a fuel) and performs thermodynamic calculations by comparing the product and reactant enthalpy. I recently switched from manually importing values from NIST Thermochemistry tables to using Cantera for the calculations.
However, I have run into a problem. When I try to obtain the enthalpy of certain molecules that ARE in the file when I check afterwards, I get an error. It says that the molecular formula could not be found. I tried to check for case sensitivity to find the molecules but that did not work. I really need help as this project is due in a month and I still have some parts to work on that are reliant on this.
Here is the test code I'm using along with the error being thrown:
import cantera as ct

def HH_Tr(file, species, initial, final):
    gas = ct.Solution(file)
    gas.TPX = initial, ct.one_atm, {species: 1.0}
    h_298 = gas.enthalpy_mass/1000000
    T_new = final
    gas.TP = T_new, ct.one_atm
    h_T = gas.enthalpy_mass/1000000
    delta_h = h_T - h_298
    print(f"Enthalpy difference (h_o - h_o(298.15)) for {species} at {T_new} K: {delta_h:.2f} J/kg")
    return delta_h

list1 = ["H2", "O2", "H2O", "CO2", "F2", "N2O4", "H2O2", "CH4", "C2H5OH", "NH3", "NH4", "CH3OH", "NO2", "CF4", "N2", "O3", "HNO3","C12H26"]
for i in list1:
    if i == "C12H26":
        val = HH_Tr("nDodecane_Reitz.yaml", i, 298.15, 1500)
    elif i == "H2" or i == "O2" or i == "H2O" or i == "CO2":
        val = HH_Tr("gri30.yaml", i, 298.15, 1500)
    else:
        val = HH_Tr("nasa_gas.yaml", i, 298.15, 1500)

The error is this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\Operational_Functional_Block\Python_Projects\Rocket Engine Generator\AdiabaticCombustor4.py", line 21, in <module>
    val = HH_Tr("nasa_gas.yaml", i, 298.15, 1500)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Public\Operational_Functional_Block\Python_Projects\Rocket Engine Generator\AdiabaticCombustor4.py", line 4, in HH_Tr
    gas = ct.Solution(file)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "cantera\\solutionbase.pyx", line 37, in cantera.solutionbase._SolutionBase.__cinit__
  File "cantera\\solutionbase.pyx", line 95, in cantera.solutionbase._SolutionBase._cinit
  File "cantera\\solutionbase.pyx", line 180, in cantera.solutionbase._SolutionBase._init_yaml
cantera._utils.CanteraError: 
*******************************************************************************
InputFileError thrown by AnyValue::getMapWhere:
Error on line 0 of C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cantera\data/nasa_gas.yaml:
Key 'phases' not found
|  Line |
|     1 | description: |-
|     2 |   This file contains data for gas phase species from the NASA thermodynamic
|     3 |   database, which is available for download from
*******************************************************************************


Process finished with exit code 1

